# What does SCM mean in unix sockets context (SCM_RIGHTS etc.)?

Tags: socket, unix-sockets

From [`man 7 unix`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)

> SCM_RIGHTS
> Send or receive a set of  open  file  descriptors  from  another
> process.  The data portion contains an integer array of the file
> descriptors.  The passed file descriptors behave as though  they
> have been created with dup(2).

There are also other concepts with SCM in them; what does SCM mean here? I didn't manage to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCM in this context stands for [“socket-level control message”](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.3/source/include/linux/socket.h#L163) (see also [the processing implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.3/source/net/core/scm.c)).